# google cloud storage file upload error using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I followed a tutorial that teach how to upload a file to google cloud and my file is now uploading to the google cloud. Uploaded files are there in the google cloud. But during the file upload process, i make those files public. I went through several tutorials and all have the same method that is given below. In here the `file` is the file i'm uploading to my bucket/

```
file.makePublic().then(() => {
      req.file.cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(gcsname);
      next();
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

But in my case, i am getting below error. In above promise, when i run my code, it wont go to the then part. It goes to the catch part of the promise.

> Cannot get legacy ACL for an object when Bucket Policy Only is enabled

Comment: It seems to me that the makePublic() method uses the legacy ACL to make the files public. Is it a requirement for your project to use the [Bucket Policy Only](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-policy-only#should-you-use) feature?

Comment: no, it is not a requirement. Can you please tell me a solution that would work for this.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest trying to [disable the Bucket Policy Only](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-bucket-policy-only#disable) and see if it works. If it does work I’ll post it as an answer.

Comment: okay, i'll check that and post if that is working